# Function to print simple plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

In an exercise I am asked to write a function `def render_plot():` which takes a set of coordinates `[(2, 3), (-1, 2), (1, -1), (0, 1)]` and renders a plot where every coordinate from the set is a star `*` and every other position is a space `⎵`. The plot should also have a frame. It would look like this:

```
######
#   *#
#*   #
# *  #
#    #
#  * #
######
```

where the star in the upper right corner is the `(2,3)` position and the bottom left corner (not the frame) is the `(-1,-1)` position.

So far this is my code:

```
def render_plot(a):
    s = ""
    l = list(zip(*plot))
    height = max(l[1])-min(l[1])+1
    widht = max(l[0])-min(l[0])+1
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(widht):
            if (i,j) in plot:
                s += "*"
```

I have tried to add line after line to a empty string, and my thought is to check if the next coordinate in the for loops are in the argument `plot` and if not, if it is the frame or the inside of the frame.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Oh, I am kinda stuck and would love sugestions to solve this exercise, sorry for not being clear :)

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: It looks like you now also need to add spaces, line breaks, and the `#` symbols for the frame to the string at the appropriate positions, and finally return or print the string.

Comment: How would I write a loop structure that can print each line with the if statments that outputs the correct symbol at the correct positions, then moves on to the next line, generating the plot.

Comment: You already have the loop structure. You just need to also add something other than a `*` symbol if you're not in a position where a `*` should go.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with the nested `for` loops, but you need to think very carefully about the values that each loop must iterate over. They are not supposed to start at zero, but at the lowest value in the data. An additional complication is that the topmost line must be printed first, so the loop for the rows must actually start with the highest y-value and iterate backwards.

```py
def render_plot(a):
    x = [point[0] for point in a]
    y = [point[1] for point in a]
    min_x = min(x)
    max_x = max(x)
    width = max_x - min_x + 1
    
    print('#' * (width + 2))
    for j in range(max(y), min(y) - 1, -1):
        s = '#'
        for i in range(min_x, max_x + 1):
            if (i, j) in a:
                s += '*'
            else:
                s += ' '
        print(s + '#')
    print('#' * (width + 2))
                
        
test = [(2, 3), (-1, 2), (1, -1), (0, 1)]
render_plot(test)
```

```
######
#   *#
#*   #
# *  #
#    #
#  * #
######
```